# Web API project structure and architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Solution Structure:

MyProject - WEBAPI

MyProject.CORE - Class Library

MyProject.Models - Class Library

MyProject.DAL - Class Library

Project References:

MyProject refers to CORE , MODELS

MyProject.CORE refers to DAL,MODELS

MyProject.DAL refers to MODELS

Project Description:

I am trying to create an application with ASP.NET MVC WEB API . so that I can call my API in future mobile applications. My idea behind this layered architecture is WEB API project will hold the front end views of my desktop application and call's the API controller methods on button click events . The event handler methods in API controller will call the Methods in the CORE project where I will implement the business logic.Then the call will be going to DAL where I will call the DB Stored Procs to insert data. As MODELS project is referred to the rest 3 , I will be able to transfer Objects across them.

Here are my questions below.

1) Can I use the same web API project above to create views of my desktop application and call the API controller methods on events like button click?

2) I don't want to expose the implementation of my business logic in CORE application to any other referencing projects. But still i need to follow a layered architecture.

How can i achieve that. Please explain with an example.

3) Is there any best architecture that i can follow with the above requirements.

4) Is this a valid architecture for WEB API and will this work?

Please take the Model example as UserModel {Name, Password, Email}

Comment: Why? What's the use of separating in different projects and not just maybe folders inside the same project? And what are you going to put in the DAL project? Smells like over-engineering to me. The only project I always start as separated is the one with the tests, so I guess you are missing the MyProject.Tests project.

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume you meant '*solution*', not '*project*'. Yes, you can keep mixed types of projects inside one solution, that is Web API for IIS hosting and WPF app that references your core.
2. This is where interfaces and dependency injection come into play. Create separate interface project to reference and use some dependency binding module like ninject or [Microsoft Locator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx)
3. When following any architecture pattern, remember that patterns were created for developers, not the other way round. What am trying to say, that when you follow any architecture, you - and only you - know what you are trying to achieve. Don't stick to any pattern if you don't know what are you doing and feel free to bend any pattern to your needs. For now keep it simple.
4. Yes.